# C Assigning Strings from File to Array of Structs Overwritten

Tags: c, arrays, file, struct

I read a line from a file in C, split it by spaces, and then assign to an array of a struct type. The problem is, everything is overwritten by the last iteration of the loop. I've simplified my code to illustrate the problem.

The struct is:

```
typedef struct place place;
struct place {
    char* name; //string, assume just 1 word 
    char* word1; //string, assume just 1 word
    char* word2; //string, assume just 1 word
};

//initialise array of the struct place
int numberPlaces = 10; //just assume this is hardcoded and we know there are 10 places (10 lines in the file)
place* places;
places = malloc(100*numberPlaces*sizeof(places));

//set values to NULL
for(int p = 0; p < numberPlaces; p++) {
    places[p].name = NULL;  
    places[p].word1 = NULL; 
    places[p].word2 = NULL; 
}
```

I read from the text file, and attempt to assign to the struct array like so:

```
FILE *file =fopen("test.txt","r"); //open text file
char data[1000]; //assume line max length is 1000
int structCount = 0; //counter so we can assign each line to a new index in struct (places) array
while (fgets(data,1000, file)!=NULL) {

    //split the line by spaces --> each line only has 3 words
    char *line;
    line = strtok(data," ");
    int c = 0;
    while(line != NULL) {
        /*each line in file would be in the format
          NAME WORD1 WORD2
        */
        if(c == 0) {
           //first word in the line is the name
           places[structCount].name = line;
        } else if(c == 1) {
           //second word in the line is 'word1'
           places[structCount].word1 = line;
        } else {
           //third word in the line is 'word2'
           places[structCount].word2 = line;
        }

        line = strtok(NULL," ");
        c++;
    }
    structCount++;

}
fclose(file); //close file
```

The problem: EVERY struct in the array now has the values from the last line of the file. Why is this? I assume I am assigning the memory wrong, but I'm not sure where/why/how?

Comment: 1) `places = malloc(100*numberPlaces*sizeof(places));` --> `places = malloc(100*numberPlaces*sizeof(*places));` 2) `places[structCount].name = line;` You are using part of same buffer.

Comment: hmm, so you're saying allocate memory to each element in the array? i.e. loop through and malloc each time?

Comment: E.g `places[structCount].name = malloc(strlen(line)+1); strcpy(places[structCount].name, line);`

Comment: works perfectly now! Thankyou @BLUEPIXY